# cannot connect to my repository in AWS Code commit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I m trying to connect to my repository in AWS code commit. However, I m keep getting:

```
fatal: unable to access `'https://git-codecommit.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo_name>/': The requested URL returned error: 403`
```

I have followed all the steps mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-unixes.html?icmpid=docs_acc_console_connect#setting-up-https-unixes-account) and [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=198356)

and also in other similar posts...

1) configure aws

2) run credential helper command

3) deactivate os keychain, since I m running on OSX.

Still I cant get it working. Anybody has an idea?